# C# program needs path to data set during install

Tags: c#, installshield

I have a c# program and it needs to set a path to some data during install.  I am using Installshield LE.  I have been trying to figure the best way to do this.  The path **must** be set during the install time.  I was wondering if there is an option I can set in installshield that will set a registry key to a path in the setup command line or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Why not set the path the first time the program is run?

Comment: What is the path?  IS does let you set registry keys to the install folder and other folders.

Comment: The path is a path to some preinstalled data. Currently it is set at runtime but the program will be installed at night on a bunch of computers and the users do not know the path to the data.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information to accurately answer. And it doesn't specify what you have done so far to address the issue. As Dave S states above you need to indicate if this is a path to a third party item, your install directory, or the target path for a component. I am not familiar with what options are available with LE, but at the very least it should allow you to write to the registry. If this is a path to a third party app, or something already installed on the machine, then look up info on AppSearch.

Answer (score 0):

Set a registry key's value data to something including `[INSTALLDIR]`. Or, if your data directory is in a directory whose identifier you know, you can use that identifier instead of INSTALLDIR. (Again, wrap it in square brackets to have Windows Installer write its value instead of its name.)